# How to control height of Message Box in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.Msg.show({  
   title:"My Title",
   msg:"Are you Sure?",                                     
   minHeight:20,
   modal:true,  
   icon:Ext.window.MessageBox.INFO, 
   buttons:Ext.MessageBox.OK
});
```

Here is my code for message box.

Do anyone have any idea how to control its height? I don't want unwanted spaces between "Are you Sure" text and ok button.

---

Tried height:20 but its no use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i have found its solution..i have just define maxHeight and it works like a charm.

Comment: Not sure what version of extjs you're using, but this doesn't seem to work for 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not work for ExtJs 4.1

I had to do this for it to work fine for me :

```
Ext.Msg.show({  
title:"My Title",
msg:"Are you Sure?",
icon:Ext.window.MessageBox.INFO, 
buttons:Ext.MessageBox.OK
}).setHeight(50);
```

You can also use the setSize() method instead for setting height and width.

Answer (score 0):

use cls and apply css padding and achieve your goal. to refer the css class, use firebug(FF) and developer tool(IE).

[image: css on message box]

Thanks

Comment: Tried .. using height:100px !important;, it will just make changes in wrapper of message box... inner css will be same...

Comment: just play with css padding

Comment: i had attached the screen shot for your reference.